# Am I safe from XSS if I remove '<' and '>' from user input'?

Tags: python, sanitize

Let's say my app takes the user input:

`1,2,3,4`

submits it to my backend server, then returns

`<table><tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th></tr></table>`

One potential security concern would be if my user uploaded:

`<script>alert('!')</script>,2,3,4`

Can I prevent all dangerous XSS attacks just by removing `<` and `>` from user input (like below in Python), or are there other characters that can hurt me?

`data = data.replace('>','').replace('<','')`

I would use my template language sanitization (Django), but since I'm making my own HTML on the backend, I can't because then it will sanitize my table too.

Comment: I will probably use [bleach](https://github.com/mozilla/bleach), but I am still interested in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I safe from XSS if I remove '<' and '>' from user input'?

No. There are *plenty* of other ways that unfiltered user input can be leveraged into an exploit. For example, consider a poorly designed piece of software that allows a user to set the color of an element:

```
<element style="color: $COLOR" />
```

A malicious user could set `$COLOR` to the string

```
blue" onload="alert(1)
```

to result in the output

```
<element style="color: blue" onload="alert(1)" />
```

Note that a input "sanitization" library like Bleach would not help here, as the input technically contained no markup! The only *general* solution is to be cautious about how and where you allow user input to be interpolated into your markup.

> I would use my template language sanitization (Django), but since I'm making my own HTML on the backend, I can't because then it will sanitize my table too.

I'm not sure what you're concerned about here. The filtering features in Django templates are only applied to content used in templates, not elsewhere in the application.

Comment: Re: the last part, since I am essentially passing html from Django views -> template, I must use ```{{ text|safe }}```, otherwise it will destroy the table I made in the backedn

Comment: So it seems like the takeaway is for XSS, anything can get you if you put it in the wrong place.

Comment: My inclination would be to avoid generating any kind of HTML in the controller -- pass the data that goes into the table to the template, and generate the table there. But yes -- that's an excellent summary of XSS protection.